# 2 months old PC not booting - What's broken?

Tags: bsod, crash

I need some help trying to find out what hardware is causing problems in my PC. Very short version: After having multiple bluescreens over several weeks, the PC is now no longer booting at all!

***My System:***
Mainboard: [Gigabyte B450 Aorus Pro](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-PRO-rev-10#sp)
CPU: [AMD Ryzen 5 2600](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-5-2600)
RAM: [2x8GB G.Skill Aegis DDR4-3000 CL16](https://www.gskill.com/en/product/f4-3000c16d-16gisb)
PSU: [be quiet! Pure Power 10 400 Watt](https://www.bequiet.com/en/powersupply/928)
GPU: [Palit GeForce GTX 1070 GameRock](http://www.palit.com/palit/vgapro.php?id=2639&lang=en)
SSD: [Crucial MX500](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/storage-ssd-mx500)
OS: Windows 10

***Problem description:***

- I built the PC myself (around mid of september)
- After a few weeks,
  the PC crashed (Bluescreen, cannot remember which error specifically)
  during gaming. This was shortly after a driver update for the GPU, so
  I went back to the previous version of the driver. This fixed the
  problem.
- Other than that, the PC was running fine for about 6 weeks

Then permanent crashes (always Bluescreens) started to occur:

- All programs still ran as usual, but sometimes the PC crashed with a Bluescreen seemingly out of nowhere
- This happened irregularly and while having different programs open (browser, games, even no program at all). Mostly after several hours of usage, but also a few times quickly after booting.
- Different exceptions occurred (with amount of appearances): 4x PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGE_AREA, 1x KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED, 1x DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION, 1x CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED, 2x SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION and 1x DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
- Sometimes the Bluescreen also said "Cause of error: nvlddmkm.sys", but mostly no cause was given
- I could provide minidumps for some of these crashes in case that helps.
- On one day (after several days without crashes), my browser was permanently crashing every few minutes (no bluescreens, only the browser closing and giving an error message). So I shutdown the PC, which worked as usual. But, the next time I tried to start the PC (about 45 min later), there was no more image on the screen and the fans were consistently running on very high (not sure if max) speed. Usually when I started the PC, the fans shortly turned up and then quickly went back to almost noiseless. Moreover, the PC can only be shutdown from this state by pressing the power button very long. Therefore I am very sure that it is not only the image that is missing, but that **the PC does not boot at all** (not even gets into BIOS)!
- During these "booting attempts", the Mainboard's warning LED for CPU is on. Every few seconds, it goes off and the LED for DRAM lights up, only to immediately go back to only the CPU LED being on. According to the mainboard's manual, this means that "the corresponding device is not working normally".

***What I tried (of course while I could still boot. All to no success):***

- Updating drivers for all kinds of devices
- Deactivating Windows Defender and using a different antivirus program instead
- Resetting the PC to a state multiple days before the first crashes occurred via the functionality built into windows
- Using the Windows utility "Verifier" caused the PC to enter a loop of permanent boots and crashes on the login screen -> I canceled this
- Testing the RAM with "MemTest6.1", I got some errors (I think this means that a read value is different from what was written before). I then tried both RAM stick solo and (wierdly enough) had no errors for either of them. Even with both sticks just switching sockets with each other, I had no more errors. Note however that I mostly tested these new configurations immediately after booting, while the very first test (which had errors) was after several hours of normal PC usage.
- After I could no longer boot, I tried changing the RAM configuration (including different stick in different slots), but this did not help in any way.

*Now, my guess is that some piece of hardware is broken. I suspect it's the mainboard, but keep in mind that I have no experience with hardware failure at all. WHAT DO YOU THINK IS BROKEN? WHAT CAN I DO TO FIND OUT? Sadly, I don't have access to any different hardware for testing purposes. I can only send stuff back to the sellers and hope for a replacement.*

I am very thankful for any tip or advice.

Kind regards,
Johannes

Comment: Could indeed be a hardware problem, but just as easily be a software problem. I would start with a fresh install of windows, just to be sure.

Comment: My hunch says hardware problem, maybe an overheating CPU.  Here's what I would do first:  Download a live Linux distro (such as Knoppix), and burn it to a DVD, using a different computer.  Boot your PC with that and see what happens.  If it runs OK, then you have isolated your problem to Windows.  In that case, I would lean toward a clean re-install.  If you DO get problems with the live Linux, that means your problem is outside Windows - most likely the hardware.  In that case, stop messing with Windows and start looking inside the PC.

Comment: Swap in a known-working full set of RAM (do not reuse the old at all) and run the Memory Test again.  If the new one works and works under other tests, then the problem was the original RAM.  If problems show up on known-working RAM, then it's something else.

Comment: Power Supply - Proper bonkers behaviour on them when the voltage regulator gives up

Comment: First of all, thanks to all of you for trying to help me! However, I want to point out that **the PC does not boot at all and does not even get into the BIOS**. There is no image at any point after powering it on. Therefore I cannot reinstall windows, boot linux, reset the BIOS options, etc. (correct me if I'm wrong).
@K7AAY Thanks for editing the question. 1) I did not select that + I cannot reset the BIOS, see above. 2) I think I applied the thermal paste correctly. I also didn't notice any unusual temperatures during the weeks where the PC ran fine. 3) Will check later, but don't think so.

Comment: (sorry, reached character limit)
4) did that, doesnt help.
(at)CharlesBurge I did not notice unusual CPU temperatures during the weeks where everything worked, but I cannot eliminate this 100%. Sadly, I don't think I could run Linux, as I can't even access the BIOS.
(at)Christopher Good idea, but I don't have any... Wouldn't the warning LED on the mainboard for "DRAM" be on if the RAM was the problem? As described in the OP, most of the time the CPU LED is lit.
@JohnnyVegas Are you sure that this behaviour is possible from broken PSU? If so, that would be a 2nd hot candidate for the cause.

Comment: A peripheral could drag the power supply voltage down to intolerable levels. Please remove the video card and unplug its power cable, disconnect every cable from the motherboard except its power cables, then connect your monitor to the motherboard video port. This test eliminates all but the PSU, memory, CPU, and motherboard, and allows us to boot if the power supply was not adequate for all devices. Start the PC with a jumper with alligator clips on each end, by connecting the power switch pins w/ red background in the Front Panel Header block as shown at http://imgur.com/a/utVj3ax

Comment: If that stripped down configuration fails to boot, obtain a power supply tester such as https://newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4RE77A8784 . ATX power supplies cannot be tested with just a multimeter.  If the tester shows the power supply is OK, then I would expect the memory most likely, followed by motherboard, and the CPU the least likely cause, based on what I found when searching at http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/ and other reliable sources, plus 35+ years of doing this for a living.